# SSRS Reports change position between instances

Tags: reporting-services, axapta, microsoft-dynamics

I have a report that is perfectly adjusted to be printed on a form with different lines, but it only prints well if I print only one, as the form is continuous, when it tries to print the second it moves slightly upwards, but still it is acceptable, The problem is when you try to print the third, it keeps moving a little up and then in this point is totally wrong, any idea.

Abraham

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that your pagination settings are correct.

If you're paper is 11" tall, you need to make sure your page size is also 11" height.  If the margins are 1" top & bottom, your body needs to be 9", regardless of what content you have in the body.  All white space in the body is included as part of the report.  If your body height is less then 9", SSRS may try to include some of the next object on the same page to make better use of the space.

After you've got your pagination set up, export to PDF and use the PDF file to send to the printer.